# ruby - delete all files with names matching a pattern

Tags: ruby, delete-file

I have multiple files (in a folder containing thousands of files), ex:

```
...
page_bonus.txt
page_code1.txt
page_code2.txt
page_text1.txt
page_text2.txt
page_text3.txt
...
```

How do I delete all page_code* files?

Note: I do not wish to use FileUtils or shell

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`Dir::glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) supports a single character wildcard (i.e. `?`).  Based on your example, you could locate the appropriate files in a given directory using `?` and then delete them.

```
Dir.glob('/home/your_username/Documents/page_code?.txt').each { |file| File.delete(file)}
```

Comment: ...and if the single character wildcard is not sufficient, use `*` to return all files and insert `select` with a block before `each`.

Comment: works even with File.join `Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), './tmp/*.png')).each`

Answer (score 2):

To delete files with a wildcard.

```
Dir.glob("/tmp/files/*").select{ |file| /MY STRING/.match file }.each { |file| File.delete(file)}
```

The regular expression within the select is used to grab the files you want.